# Scatter plot size on "tooltip"

Tags: c3

How *to retrieve the radius*(or size) of a *scatter plot* on tooltip.

```
r : function(d) {

       if (d.value != null) {
            var size = datajson[k++]["total"];

            return size;
       }
```

I have done something like this..So the tooltip should show the size when i point on that bubble. How to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the size to the d object

```
r: function (d) {
    if (d.value != null) {
        var size = datajson[k++]["total"];
        d.size = size;
        return size;
    }
}
```

and retrieve it when you show your tooltip

```
tooltip: {
    contents: function (d) {
        if (d[0].value != null) {
            return d[0].size;
        }
    }
},
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f0cotcqp/

Comment: thanks.. is there any way to append text inside a bubble in scatter plot.For example:its size should be displayed ..

Comment: Sadly, not that I'm aware of. You might want to check if it's possible in d3. But what would you do if the bubble is small?

Comment: thanks for the reply .. if the bubble size is small the font size should also decrease with it