# dc.js scatter plot with variable symbol size

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

What will be a good way in a scatter chart to have different point/symbol sizes?

We want to make the scatter point sizes larger based on count of same record value. Currently we use http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-brushing.html which has a single point when we have data of same values controlled by symbolSize.

We want the symbolSize to vary based on the count of record values.More the data of same value larger the point size.

I am looking for something like the c3.js jsfiddle example in [Scatter plot size on "tooltip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936352/scatter-plot-size-on-tooltip) .

Comment: Right now the symbol size [encodes the count and selection state](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/scatter-plot.js#L48-L56): empty is `hiddenSize`, filtered out is `excludedSize`, filtered in is `symbolSize`. It would be good to allow this but I don't see how to do it with the current API. Willing to make a small change to the code?

Comment: I see. sure, that sounds good. Do you mean make code change for scatterPlot in local?

Comment: Yeah I'd add a method `sizeAccessor` (defaulted to the code I linked above), or `symbol`, and then you can modify the behavior  of the library from outside. If you get it working, please file a PR. If this is still not clear, let's continue the conversation in a github issue.

Comment: That sounds good. Thanks.

Comment: Added this issue to track the feature: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1205